# inner join a temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
WITH  temp(k)  AS (VALUES (15252332445), (15253665080), (15241848778),
(11813086136), (15253665080) ) LEFT join hello.transaction_job B on
B.id=temp.k SELECT * FROM temp,B.id,B.msisdn
```

Trying to join a common table expression with standard table, but failed

Can you guys tell me why?

[image: error im getting when i run the query]

Comment: and you are going to tell us the error :-)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Take smaller steps. Make a small query work, then add part after part.

Comment: Properly formatting your query will also help a lot in understanding the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SELECT` needs to be *before* the JOIN as with every join

```
WITH  temp(k)  AS (
   VALUES (15252332445), (15253665080), (15241848778),
          (11813086136), (15253665080)
)
SELECT B.id, B.msisdn
FROM temp t
  LEFT join hello.transaction_job B on  B.id = t.k;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wanted smth like:

```
WITH  temp(k)  AS (VALUES (15252332445), (15253665080), (15241848778),
(11813086136), (15253665080) ) 
, b as (select * from temp LEFT join hello.transaction_job B on
B.id=temp.k)
SELECT * FROM temp,B.id,B.msisdn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write using `union` within cte

```
WITH TEMP (k)
AS (
    SELECT 15252332445

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 15253665080

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 15241848778

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 11813086136

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 15253665080
    )
SELECT B.id, B.msisdn
FROM TEMP t
LEFT JOIN hello.transaction_job B ON B.id = t.k
```

Comment: I am just suggesting an alternate way, that's all. +1 for yours already its good feasible answer